# Trying to toggle between icon to text on my navigation using React

Tags: reactjs, hover, icons, toggle, jsx

I have some code down and it works but my problem is that it changes all of the icons at the same time when i scroll over just one. I only want the icon that I hover over to change, so any help would be appreciated.

```
export default class Home extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isHovered: false};
    this.toggleHover = this.toggleHover.bind(this);
  }

  toggleHover() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({isHovered: !prevState.isHovered}));
  }

  render() {
    return (
          <section className="info-section">
            <div className="logo">
              MATT
            </div>
            <div className="info-box">
              <ul className="nav-links">
                <li onMouseEnter={this.toggleHover} onMouseLeave={this.toggleHover}>
                  {this.state.isHovered
                    ? <a className="home active" href="/">Home</a>
                    : <a className="home active" href="/"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} /></a>
                  }
                </li>
                <li onMouseEnter={this.toggleHover} onMouseLeave={this.toggleHover}>
                  {this.state.isHovered
                    ? <a href="/about">About</a>
                    : <a href="/about"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUser} /></a>
                  }
                </li>
```

Comment: Hi,

From the code you send we can see that there is two icons right ?

The thing is that you link both icons with your state `isHovered`

Every time you hover one, it change the state `isHovered`, but both of your icons react on the state of your component. If you want to change a particular one you need some ID on where your set your icons.

Comment: Please can someone help me solve this I don't know how to add ID to the element.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use CSS.

```
<ul className="nav-links">
  <li>
    <a href="/">
      <span>Home</span>
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/about">
      <span>Home</span>
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUser} />
    </a>
  </li>
  ...

a {
  span {
    display: none;
  }

  &:hover {
    span {
      display: block;
    }
    /* hide the icon base on their html tag or class */
    i {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}
```

If you really want to handle this through Javascript (which I'm not suggesting), you can try this.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    hover: ""
  };
  handleMouseEnter = key => {
    this.setState({ hover: key });
  };
  handleMouseLeave = () => {
    this.setState({ hover: "" });
  };

  render() {
    const { hover } = this.state;
    return (
      <ul>
        <li
          onMouseEnter={() => this.handleMouseEnter("home")}
          onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}
        >
          <a href="/">
            {hover === "home" ? <span>Hover Home</span> : <span>Home</span>}
          </a>
        </li>
        <li
          onMouseEnter={() => this.handleMouseEnter("about")}
          onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}
        >
          <a href="/about">
            {hover === "about" ? <span>Hover about</span> : <span>about</span>}
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @AsiaArgento1 I add another example.